# Display one to many mapping using sql in mybatis

Tags: sql, mysqli, mybatis

I have to tables

```
Tasks:
 id
 title
 Description

Task_reply_mapping
task_id
parent_id
```

I have written the following query to get the data

```
    select t1.id,t1.title,t1.description,t2.id,t2.title,t2.description
from tasks t1
left join Task_reply_mapping trm on t1.id =  trm.task_id 
    left join tasks t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    order by fe.created_at desc limit 0,10
```

This seems to be working fine but its not populating the data correctly. I want to know if this query is correct?

In my mapper file I have

```
  <resultMap id="TaskResultMap" type="com.mycom.myproj.bean.TaskBean">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="id" />
    <result column="title" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="title" />
    <result column="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="description" />
  <collection ofType="com.mycom.myproj.bean.TaskBean" property="replyTask">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="id" />
        <result column="title" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="title" />
        <result column="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="description" />
   </collection>
  </resultMap>
```

Or I am doing something wrong in mapper class.

Records in objects are placed like at first index its putting the latest task whether its reply or new task and so on.

It should insert records like this

```
   Task1
     --1st reply task
     --2nd reply task
  Task 2
      --1st reply task
      --2nd reply task
```

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: What's the `left join tasks t2 on t2.id = t1.id` for?

Comment: Hi Linus, that I tried to put a self join to get data for reply tasks but I think thats not the way to do self join

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd `join` has to be with the `Task_reply_mapping` table:

```
select t1.id,
       t1.title,
       t1.description,
       t2.id,
       t2.title,
       t2.description
  from tasks t1
       left join Task_reply_mapping trm
           on t1.id = trm.task_id 
       left join tasks t2
           on t2.id = trm.parent_id
```

[Here is a demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa1dc/2)

Comment: Hi Linus, It seems correct but its not mapping data correctly with mapper class. Do you have any idea why it is?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the problem is.

I think maybe the query and the mapping are not correct.

Try this:

```
select 
    t1.id
    ,t1.title
    ,t1.description
    ,t2.id as id_2
    ,t2.title as title_2
    ,t2.description as description_2
from tasks t1
    left join Task_reply_mapping trm on t1.id =  trm.task_id 
    left join tasks t2 on t2.id = t1.id
order by fe.created_at desc limit 0,10
```

Mapping

```
<resultMap id="TaskResultMap" type="com.mycom.myproj.bean.TaskBean">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="id" />
    <result column="title" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="title" />
    <result column="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="description" />
    <collection ofType="com.mycom.myproj.bean.TaskBean" property="replyTask">
    <id column="id_2" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="id" />
        <result column="title_2" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="title" />
        <result column="description_2" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="description" />
   </collection>
</resultMap>
```

In you query, you have to `id`, two ´title`and two`description` so the problem could be there.